# Changing the overall size of a percentage based star rating display in css

Tags: html, css

I'm looking over this [codepen css star display](https://codepen.io/Bluetidepro/pen/GkpEa) and I would like to know if I can change the overall size of the stars? I tried setting the font-size to 15px but it scewed the stars so that they didn't overlap anymore.

```css
@import "lesshat";
// Method 1) Pure CSS
.star-ratings-css {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  color: #c5c5c5;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0 #a2a2a2;
  &-top {
    color: #e7711b;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  &-bottom {
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    z-index: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="star-ratings-css">
  <div class="star-ratings-css-top" style="width: 84%"><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span></div>
  <div class="star-ratings-css-bottom"><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are changing `font-size` only. `font-size` and `width` are related to each other. If you want to set `font-size: 15px` then you have to set `width: 60px` i.e. multiple of 4.

Here is codepen link : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vRBjyG

Comment: just curious though, if I wanted to use em as a size what would that be?

Comment: I did not try but as I told `font-size` and `width` are relative so in 1:4 proportion it should work

Answer (score -2):

Just add span {display: inline-block} and change the font-size for the .star-ratings-css as required.

```
@import "lesshat";
// Method 1) Pure CSS
span {
  display: inline-block;  
}
.star-ratings-css {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  color: #c5c5c5;
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0 #a2a2a2;
  &-top {
    color: #e7711b;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  &-bottom {
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 0;
  }
}

<div class="star-ratings-css">
  <div class="star-ratings-css-top" style="width: 84%"><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span></div>
  <div class="star-ratings-css-bottom"><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this in the code pen and it still scwews the stars. Please post the code pen example if you can

Comment: decreasing the size to 15px messes up the overlay